# Need Python to Remove everything after a comma in external file while checking user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

So, Basically, I need my python code to read each line from an external file and remove everything after a comma.  Then, it should check the user input with the new string.

Just like a verification process, where a user signs up and then the code checks whether the username is taken

But in the external file, user details are stored as:
  'username,password'

Here is my code:

```
    LogFile = 'accounts.txt'
    invalidUserName = False
    Uusername = input("Please enter your desired username: ")
    while len(Uusername) < 3 or len(Uusername) > 16:
        Uusername = input("Username is not between the length of 3 and 16, please re-enter: ")

    with open(LogFile) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        contnt = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]
        passlist = []
        userlist = []
        for line in content:
            try:
                userlist.append(line.split(",")[0])
                passlist.append(line.split(",")[1])
            except IndexError:
                pass
        for username in userlist:
            while username == Uusername:
                Uusername = input(('Username is taken, please enter another one: '))
                invalidUserName = True

    if not invalidUserName:
        password = input("Please enter your desired password: ")
        while len(password) < 3 or len(password) > 16:
            password = input("Password is not between the length of 3 and 16, please re-enter: ")
        while password == username:
            password = input("Password cannot be the same as the username, please re-enter: ")
        VerPW = input("Please verify your password: ")
        while VerPW != password:
            VerPW = input("Passwords do not match, try again: ")
        file = open ('accounts.txt','a')
        file.write (username +','+password + "\n")
        file.flush()
        file.close
        print ("Details stored successfully")
```

After line 5, I need the code to check usernames from the external file, without everything after the commas and ask the user to input again if a username already exists

Comment: oh gosh, are those passwords in plaintext?

Comment: Now, what have you tried so far? show us some code. What specific problem are you stuck with? See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list.txt:

```
emkay,123
alibaba,420

khanbaba,5647
naughty_princess,3242
whatthehack,657
```

and then:

```
logFile = "list.txt"

with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]


# list to store the passwords
passList = []

# list to store the usernames
userList = []
for line in content:
    userList.append(line.split(",")[0])
    passList.append(line.split(",")[1])


print(userList)
print(passList)

user_inp = input("Enter a username: ")

for username in userList:
    if username == user_inp:
        print("Username: {}, already taken. Please try a different username".format(username))
```

OUTPUT:

```
['emkay', 'alibaba', 'khanbaba', 'naughty_princess', 'whatthehack']
['123', '420', '5647', '3242', '657']
Enter a username: naughty_princess
Username: naughty_princess, already taken. Please try a different username
```

**EDIT:**

If you want the loop to stop when a username is found. simply, `break` away.

```
for username in userList:
    if username == user_inp:
        print("Username: {}, already taken. Please try a different username".format(username))
        break
```

**EDIT 2:**

to apply that in the code you just posted,

```
if username == Uusername:
       Uusername = ('Username is taken, please enter another one: ')
       break     # or use continue as it looks like you need it
```

**EDIT 3:**

Your code fixed, you need a boolean flag for the invalid users and proceed as follow:

```
LogFile = 'accounts.txt'
invalidUserName = False
Uusername = input("Please enter your desired username: ")
while len(Uusername) < 3 or len(Uusername) > 16:
    Uusername = input("Username is not between the length of 3 and 16, please re-enter: ")

with open(LogFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    contnt = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]
    passlist = []
    userlist = []
    for line in content:
        try:
            userlist.append(line.split(",")[0])
            passlist.append(line.split(",")[1])
        except IndexError:
            pass
    print(userlist)
    for username in userlist:
        if username == Uusername:
            print('Username is taken, please enter another one:')
            invalidUserName = True
            break
if not invalidUserName:
    password = input("Please enter your desired password: ")
    while len(password) < 3 or len(password) > 16:
        password = input("Password is not between the length of 3 and 16, please re-enter: ")
    while password == username:
        password = input("Password cannot be the same as the username, please re-enter: ")
    VerPW = input("Please verify your password: ")
    while VerPW != password:
        VerPW = input("Passwords do not match, try again: ")
    file = open ('accounts.txt','a')
    file.write (username +','+password + "\n")
    file.flush()
    file.close
    print ("Details stored successfully")
```

**EDIT 4:**

```
LogFile = 'accounts.txt'
invalidUserName = False
while True:
    Uusername = input("Please enter your desired username: ")
    while len(Uusername) < 3 or len(Uusername) > 16:
        Uusername = input("Username is not between the length of 3 and 16, please re-enter: ")

    with open(LogFile) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        contnt = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]
        passlist = []
        userlist = []
        for line in content:
            try:
                userlist.append(line.split(",")[0])
                passlist.append(line.split(",")[1])
            except IndexError:
                pass
        print(userlist)
        for username in userlist:
            if username == Uusername:
                print('Username is taken, please enter another one:')
                invalidUserName = True
                break
    if not invalidUserName:
        password = input("Please enter your desired password: ")
        while len(password) < 3 or len(password) > 16:
            password = input("Password is not between the length of 3 and 16, please re-enter: ")
        while password == username:
            password = input("Password cannot be the same as the username, please re-enter: ")
        VerPW = input("Please verify your password: ")
        while VerPW != password:
            VerPW = input("Passwords do not match, try again: ")
        file = open ('accounts.txt','a')
        file.write (username +','+password + "\n")
        file.flush()
        file.close
        print ("Details stored successfully")

        exit_now = input("Press 1 to exit")

        if '1' in exit_now:
            break
```

Comment: It works up until I need it to check, It seperates the username and password to the arrays, but when I need it to check and stop if a username is found, the code just carrys on

Comment: I've tried it, check my question, I put my code in there

Comment: @Yssr I have, look at ath Edit 2 as well.

Comment: It still just goes to the password section, it doesnt stop, even though the username is already in the array

Comment: @Yssr did you put `break` or `continue` after the line as I suggested in Edit 2 of my answer.

Comment: @Yssr check Edit 3.

Comment: One last question, after I get the user to enter a valid input, how do I make it go back to ask and enter a password?  It just ends after they enter a valid username

Comment: @Yssr you need to re-structure your loop then, `while not invalidUserName` and the rest of the code inside it.

Comment: Im sorry, where should I restructure it?

Comment: Because I replaced ```if not InvalidUserName``` to while and it still doesnt work

Comment: @Yssr Check Edit 4.

Comment: Now, once I enter a valid username after entering an invalid one, it just keep telling me to enter my desired username, it doesnt move onto the password sequence

Comment: @Yssr Hold on, Ill add more details in a while.

Comment: It doesnt matter, I've fixed it now, thanks for your help though, it REALLY helped me out, big time